# How do I set the context root for a dartium launch?

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

How do I set up a dartium launch so that the application is available at localhost:3030 instead of the default localhost:3030/path/file?

Answer (score 0):

That is still not possible but will probably be added to `pub serve` sometimes.
AFAIK DartEditor should `pub serve` in the future instead of the built-in web server.

see also

- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15020
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15978

I couldn't find the post where AFAIR Seth Ladd posted a request that `pub serve` should provide an option to serve an application in the root directory.

It should be possible to serve a Dart application by a custom server and use the DartEditor debugger anyway.
There were some bugs recently but I think this should work now. I don't know if it's supported to create a launch configuration for this - but I think so.